# if statement not returning a value

Tags: javascript, if-statement, calculator

I am trying to make a simple price calculator based on a total area value calculated by user input fields. So far most all of the program operates correctly, except the if statement that will determine the price rate based on the total sqin, does not return a value. At this point it is only setup for the Economy selection of the first drop down. The other selections are set to a constant value and work as expected. Any help with this is greatly appreciated as I am still a javascript novice.

```js
/*eslint-env browser*/

var mytotalsq;

function getEconPrice() {
  var EconPrice = 0;
  if (mytotalsq <= 199) {
    return EconPrice.value = .40;
  }
  if (mytotalsq >= 200 && mytotalsq <= 299) {
    return EconPrice.value = .22;
  }
  return EconPrice;
}

var vinyl_prices = new Array();
vinyl_prices["None"] = 0;
vinyl_prices["Econ"] = getEconPrice();
vinyl_prices["Inter"] = .25;
vinyl_prices["HPerf"] = .35;
vinyl_prices["HiTack"] = .75;
vinyl_prices["Ref"] = .75;

var laminate_prices = new Array();
laminate_prices["None"] = 1;
laminate_prices["NoLam"] = 1;
laminate_prices["StanLam"] = 1.43;
laminate_prices["HPLam"] = 1.7;

function getStickerPrice() {
  var StickerPrice = 0;
  var theForm = document.forms["stickerform"];
  var selectedVinyl = theForm.elements["vinyl"];
  StickerPrice = vinyl_prices[selectedVinyl.value];
  return StickerPrice;
}

function getLaminatePrice() {
  var LaminatePrice = 0;
  var theForm = document.forms["stickerform"];
  var selectedLaminate = theForm.elements["laminate"];
  LaminatePrice = laminate_prices[selectedLaminate.value];
  return LaminatePrice;
}

function calculateTotal() {
  var myheight = document.getElementById('height').value;
  var mywidth = document.getElementById('width').value;
  var myquan = document.getElementById('quan').value;
  var totalsq = document.getElementById('totalsq');
  mytotalsq = mywidth * myheight * myquan;
  totalsq.value = mytotalsq;
  var stickerPrice = mytotalsq * getStickerPrice() * getLaminatePrice();
  var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
  divobj.style.display = 'block';
  divobj.innerHTML = "Total $" + stickerPrice;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
  <title>RMSticker Pricing</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/stickercalc.js"></script>
  <link href="css/sticker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrap">
    <form action="" id="stickerform" onsubmit="return false;">
      <div>
        <div class="cont_order">
          <fieldset>
            <legend>RMSticker</legend>
            <label>Height</label>
            <input id="height" type="text" />
            <label>Width</label>
            <input id="width" type="text" />
            <label>Quantity</label>
            <input id="quan" type="text" oninput="calculateTotal()" />
            <input id="totalsq" name="totalsq" type="text" />
            <br/><br/>

            <label>Vinyl</label>

            <select id="vinyl" name='vinyl' onchange="calculateTotal()">
              <option value="None">Select Vinyl</option>
              <option value="Econ">Economy</option>
              <option value="Inter">Intermediate</option>
              <option value="HPerf">High Performance</option>
              <option value="HiTack">High Tack</option>
              <option value="Ref">Reflective</option>
            </select>
            <br/><br/>


            <label>Laminate</label>

            <select id="laminate" name='laminate' onchange="calculateTotal()">
              <option value="None">Select Laminate</option>
              <option value="NoLam">None</option>
              <option value="StanLam">Standard</option>
              <option value="HPLam">High Performance</option>
            </select>

            <br/><br/>

            <label>Select Finish</label>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedfinish" value="Matte" onclick="calculateTotal()" />Matte</label><br/>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedfinish" value="Satin" onclick="calculateTotal()" />Satin(Only available on laminated stickers)</label><br/>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedfinish" value="Gloss" onclick="calculateTotal()" />Gloss</label><br/>



            <div id="totalPrice"></div>

          </fieldset>
        </div>

                       
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <!--End of wrap-->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Well, your code immediately throws `"Uncaught ReferenceError: hideTotal is not defined"`, so you should fix that first.

Comment: Ok fixed that. It was not part of the js anyway, it was referencing a function that had not been made. Program runs without that error but is still not returning a value.

Comment: `EconPrice` is initially the numeric value `0`, but you're referencing it like an object by doing `EconPrice.value`. Either initialize `EconPrice` as an object or remove the `.value` (the latter seems to be more aligned with your intentions).

Comment: There is a lot wrong with the code you have. But, the main issue is that the lines that set up your new array and attempt to populate it run immediately (before the user has had a chance to enter any data) and so your array is empty when you attempt to get information out of it.

Comment: @B.Fleming I didn't realize I still had it that way. I added the .value because  it was returning NaN and I was trying to make sure it was an integer and not a string. It didn't seem to function without it either.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I'm sure there is I am by no means fluent in javascript.  The laminate_price array will always be a constant as it is now, so I don't know if it matters or not when it populates, but the vinyl_prices array should be dependent on mytotalsq. Is there a way to keep it from populating before user inputs.

Comment: @skully See my comment above - - that's your real issue. It certainly does matter when the array populates because you are immediately running `vinyl_prices["Econ"] = getEconPrice();` and at that point, `mytotalsq` is declared but undefined. You need to wait until `calculateTotal` has been run before `mytotoalsq` will have a value to check.

Comment: You have to decide when the appropriate time to populate the array is and move all that code to a function that runs at that time. As it is now, I have no idea what your logic is trying to accomplish so only you would know when that time is.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thank you that makes total sense. Should I put it inside another function that is invoked when calculateTotal is executed. Sorry I was typing this reply and didn't see you other until I posted it.

Comment: I guess. You have to call it after the user has entered data, but before calculate does it's thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that the lines that set up your new array and attempt to populate it run immediately (before the user has had a chance to enter any data) and so your array is empty when you attempt to get information out of it.

Moving the lines that populate the arrays (but not the lines that declare the arrays) into the `calculate` function solves the problem.

```js
/*eslint-env browser*/

var mytotalsq;

function getEconPrice() {
  var EconPrice = 0;
  if (mytotalsq <= 199) {
    return EconPrice.value = .40;
  }
  if (mytotalsq >= 200 && mytotalsq <= 299) {
    return EconPrice.value = .22;
  }
  return EconPrice;
}


function getStickerPrice() {
  var StickerPrice = 0;
  var theForm = document.forms["stickerform"];
  var selectedVinyl = theForm.elements["vinyl"];
  StickerPrice = vinyl_prices[selectedVinyl.value];
  return StickerPrice;
}

function getLaminatePrice() {
  var LaminatePrice = 0;
  var theForm = document.forms["stickerform"];
  var selectedLaminate = theForm.elements["laminate"];
  LaminatePrice = laminate_prices[selectedLaminate.value];
  return LaminatePrice;
}

var vinyl_prices = new Array();
var laminate_prices = new Array();

function calculateTotal() {


vinyl_prices["None"] = 0;
vinyl_prices["Econ"] = getEconPrice();
vinyl_prices["Inter"] = .25;
vinyl_prices["HPerf"] = .35;
vinyl_prices["HiTack"] = .75;
vinyl_prices["Ref"] = .75;


laminate_prices["None"] = 1;
laminate_prices["NoLam"] = 1;
laminate_prices["StanLam"] = 1.43;
laminate_prices["HPLam"] = 1.7;

  var myheight = document.getElementById('height').value;
  var mywidth = document.getElementById('width').value;
  var myquan = document.getElementById('quan').value;
  var totalsq = document.getElementById('totalsq');
  mytotalsq = mywidth * myheight * myquan;
  totalsq.value = mytotalsq;
  var stickerPrice = mytotalsq * getStickerPrice() * getLaminatePrice();
  var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
  divobj.style.display = 'block';
  divobj.innerHTML = "Total $" + stickerPrice;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
  <title>RMSticker Pricing</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/stickercalc.js"></script>
  <link href="css/sticker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrap">
    <form action="" id="stickerform" onsubmit="return false;">
      <div>
        <div class="cont_order">
          <fieldset>
            <legend>RMSticker</legend>
            <label>Height</label>
            <input id="height" type="text" />
            <label>Width</label>
            <input id="width" type="text" />
            <label>Quantity</label>
            <input id="quan" type="text" oninput="calculateTotal()" />
            <input id="totalsq" name="totalsq" type="text" />
            <br/><br/>

            <label>Vinyl</label>

            <select id="vinyl" name='vinyl' onchange="calculateTotal()">
              <option value="None">Select Vinyl</option>
              <option value="Econ">Economy</option>
              <option value="Inter">Intermediate</option>
              <option value="HPerf">High Performance</option>
              <option value="HiTack">High Tack</option>
              <option value="Ref">Reflective</option>
            </select>
            <br/><br/>


            <label>Laminate</label>

            <select id="laminate" name='laminate' onchange="calculateTotal()">
              <option value="None">Select Laminate</option>
              <option value="NoLam">None</option>
              <option value="StanLam">Standard</option>
              <option value="HPLam">High Performance</option>
            </select>

            <br/><br/>

            <label>Select Finish</label>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedfinish" value="Matte" onclick="calculateTotal()" />Matte</label><br/>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedfinish" value="Satin" onclick="calculateTotal()" />Satin(Only available on laminated stickers)</label><br/>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedfinish" value="Gloss" onclick="calculateTotal()" />Gloss</label><br/>



            <div id="totalPrice"></div>

          </fieldset>
        </div>

                       
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <!--End of wrap-->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch Scott it now works as I had anticipated! I really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: @skully You're welcome. Don't forget to mark this as "the" answer.

Comment: Sorry I thought I had and didn't see you comment until now. Thanks again. Since you helped me get past this hump I have made some changes and added some functions to help it work better for what I need. Without this I might still be stumped, I used to do a little javascript stuff years back but definitely a little rusty, but your help got me going again.